# Find a basis of $U_i$, given subspace $U_1$,$U_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been given two subspaces, $U_1$, $U_2$, which are as follows :

$ U_1=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a&b \\c&d\\ \end{pmatrix}: b=0\right\}$

$ U_2=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a&b \\c&d\\ \end{pmatrix}: a=c=d\right\}$

I need to find a basis for $U_i$?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $U_1$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
=
a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
+
c\begin{pmatrix} ? & ? \\ ? & ? \end{pmatrix}
+
d\begin{pmatrix} ? & ? \\ ? & ? \end{pmatrix}
$$

For $U_2$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ a & a \end{pmatrix}
=
a\begin{pmatrix} ? & ? \\ ? & ? \end{pmatrix}
+
b\begin{pmatrix} ? & ? \\ ? & ? \end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint 1*

> The number of free parameters will be the dimension, that is, the number of elements in a basis.

*Hint 2*

> Write a generic matrix of $U_{i}$ as a sum of matrices, such that a given parameter occurs in one and only one of the summands.

*Hint 3*

> Now *take the parameter out* in each summand, meaning writing for instance $$\begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} = a \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$